# Reading API data and Pulling Images from Namespace

Tags: json, swift, xcode, api, dictionary

I am pulling some information from an API. The goal is you input an image and it returns your celebrity lookalikes. I am having trouble finding a way to pull a picture of the celebrity in the app. Is that even possible from the API results?

```
confidence = "0.7630000114440918";
"face_uuid" = "e743a4cd-3570-1030-b683-8049ebc209e6";
"is_match" = 1;
"person_id" = "Madonna@celebrities.betaface.com";
```

The API documentation vaguely states

"Betaface: all@celebrities.betaface.com – 40000+ faces of famous people all@part01.wikipedia.org,all@part02.wikipedia.org,all@part03.wikipedia.org,all@part04.wikipedia.org,all@part05.wikipedia.org,all@part06.wikipedia.org – 3016703 faces from wikipedia"

Comment: What API are you using? It seems it returns recognition results (Madonna) not images.

Comment: Betaface API @TonyNguyen, do you have an idea how i can pull images from the web as an alternative?